# New list made of the average of consecutive neighboring elements from a list

Tags: python

What would be the best way to write a new list where the new list is based on (is the average of) several elements from the previous list? Is a regular for-loop the only solution?

For example, the average of each two consecutive elements,

```
a= [4,2,5,3,2]
```

Output:

```
a_ave=[3, 3.5, 4, 2.5]
```

(4+2)/2=3, (2+5)/2=3.5, etc.

Comment: `zip(a, a[1:])` can help.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x:sum(x)/2,zip(a,a[1:])))`, just a disclaimer, it's a for loop underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't avoid the **O(N)** complexity here, because you can't skip iterating. In terms of lesser lines of code, maybe something like this?

```
print([(a[index] + a[index + 1]) / 2 for index in range(len(a) - 1)])
```